# DataGridView CellContentChanged event - StackOverflow Exception - Weird Situation

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am trying to take values from a datagridviewcell and calculate and change the value of another cell.

For some reason I am running into stack overflow exception, the code:

```
private void grdWarehouseCounts_CellContentChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  // calculate variance
  DataGridView sendergrid = (DataGridView)sender;
  if (sendergrid.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 3)
  {
    decimal Qty = Convert.ToDecimal(sendergrid.Rows[sendergrid.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
    decimal Count = Convert.ToDecimal(sendergrid.Rows[sendergrid.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
                sendergrid.Rows[sendergrid.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = Qty - Count;
  }
}
```

Here is the grid:

[image]

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, and its driving me insane.

Can anyone else see something I am doing wrong, as I am fairly new at this?

Any common gotchas?

Chris

Comment: I'm not too familiar with winforms stuff, but is it possible that you are firing the `grdWarehouseCounts_CellContentChanged` event from inside of itself, by changing the cell value in the last line of your if statement?

Comment: using the   if (sendergrid.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 3)
      should prevent that scenario, correct?  The column index has to be 3 - and the column im modifying is 4

Comment: I think what @AbeMiessler mentioned is exactly what happened.

Comment: Hrrm that's a good point Chris.  One easy way to check would be to comment out the last line of your `if`.  If you do that does the error go away?

Comment: @ChrisNorris You check if the selected cell's column index is equal to 3. When you change something inside the `CellContentChanged` event your selected cell stays the same. So it keeps entering the if clause anyways and keeps calling itself again and again.

Comment: how do I avoid that loop and still set the value with the calculated number

Comment: its supposed to be qty-count=variance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (instead of using `SelectedCells[0]`, use `e.ColumnIndex` and `e.RowIndex`):

```
private void grdWarehouseCounts_CellContentChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  // calculate variance
  DataGridView sendergrid = (DataGridView)sender;

  //if (sendergrid.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 3)
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
  {
    decimal Qty = Convert.ToDecimal(sendergrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
    decimal Count = Convert.ToDecimal(sendergrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
    sendergrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = Qty - Count;
  }
}
```

Comment: hattenn has already correctly pointed out that your SelectedCell wasn't changing and it ran into an infinite loop..